# Differentiate between NSWindow close and Multiple-Tab-NSWindow close?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, macos-sierra, appkit

I'm trying to make my application call hide when the user attempts to close the last window via the red button.

Note: The tabs mentioned below are part of the sierra automatic tabbing feature.

I'm aware that I can hide the application with `NSApplication.shared().hide()`, however, I only want to do this when the user has tried to close the last open window (meaning, the red button that would close ALL tabs for that window). However, I want to permit the close buttons on the tabs to perform normally, and close the tab.

So far a tab closure and a window closure appear identical in the API and I'm having a hard time achieving the behavior I want.  Is there a way to determine if the is being closed via its red close button, or its tab close button?

Comment: Don't call hide when the user attempts to close the last window. The close button should close, not hide. Quit after closing the last window or disable closing the last window or hide the window when the app isn't the front most app.

Comment: I am inspired a bit by Finder's behavior. If you have multiple tabs in your last finder window, closing and reopening that window does not seem to affect the tabs on reopen.  However, in pages and Safari all tabs are lost on close.... bah!

Comment: The Finder doesn't hide itself when I close the window. It stays active and the front most app. The Finder restores a window when it is actived. How do you reopen a window in the Finder?

Comment: By clicking the finder icon again it reopens the final window that was closed. (including all the tabs). You suspect it's reconstructing all those items instead of just hiding?  I'd like to mimic the behavior, but the framework does not appear to communicate a multi-window close. I just get a separate close event for each tab's NSWindow.

Comment: The Finder probably caches its windows. There aren't any notifications or delegate methods you can use to detect closure of the 'superwindow'. Maybe a workaround is comparing the window and the window of the current event.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

- I've only been working with Swift/Cocoa for a few weeks.
- There's probably a better way of doing this.

So I could not find an easy way of doing this. The idea behind my implementation is to call a debounced function when a window closes. Since clicking the "X" in the corner closes all windows, the debouncing will allow you to have a function called once when it's all done.

There's some other stuff too: You've got to cache the number of windows in a tab. You've got to keep a list of the windows being closed.

But in the end, you can differentiate between:

- Closing multiple tabs in a window ("Close other tabs")
- Closing a single tab in a window
- Closing a whole window of tabs
- Closing a window without tabs

Anyways, here's my implementation. You'll need [`debounce` from here](https://gist.github.com/simme/b78d10f0b29325743a18c905c5512788/):

```
// Stands for TabbedWindowCloseDebouncer
class TWCDebouncer {
    private static var Debouncers = [NSWindowTabGroup: () -> Void]()
    private static var TabStartCounts = [NSWindowTabGroup: Int]()
    private static var Windows = [NSWindowTabGroup: [NSWindow]]()
    private static var LastTabGroup: NSWindowTabGroup?

    func handleClose(window: NSWindow) {
        // This handles a window without tabs.
        // Check presence in Debouncers, otherwise it will also catch the last
        // window of a tabbed window closing.
        if window.tabbedWindows == nil && TWCDebouncer.Debouncers[window.tabGroup!] == nil {
            // You can consider this to be the same as closing a whole window.
            return
        }

        // This could probably lead to problems.
        TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup = window.tabGroup

        // Store the initial tab count.
        if TWCDebouncer.TabStartCounts[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] == nil {
            TWCDebouncer.TabStartCounts[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = window.tabbedWindows?.count
        }

        // Initialize the list of windows closing.
        if TWCDebouncer.Windows[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] == nil {
            TWCDebouncer.Windows[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = []
        }

        // Set up the debounced function.
        if TWCDebouncer.Debouncers[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] == nil {
            TWCDebouncer.Debouncers[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = debounce(delay: .milliseconds(20), action: {
                let countAfter = TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup?.windows.count ?? 0

                print(TWCDebouncer.Windows[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!])
                if countAfter == 0 {
                    // All windows were closed.
                } else {
                    // One or more windows were closed in the tab group
                }

                // Reset.
                TWCDebouncer.Debouncers[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = nil
                TWCDebouncer.TabStartCounts[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = nil
                TWCDebouncer.Windows[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!] = nil
                TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup = nil
            })
        }

        // Store the window.
        TWCDebouncer.Windows[TWCDebouncer.LastTabGroup!]?.append(window)
        // Call the debounced function.
        TWCDebouncer.Debouncers[window.tabGroup!]!()
    }
}
```

To use it, I've put it on my `WindowController`. I had to put it in `windowShouldClose`, by the time `windowWillClose` is called, `window.tabbedWindows` is `nil`.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    var closeDebouncer = TWCDebouncer()

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        self.closeDebouncer.handleClose(window: self.window!)
        return true
    }
}
```